# MySQL C++ connector in MVS2019 issue

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2019, database-connection

I am using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_W4zt5sR1M&ab_channel=BoostMyTool  to make simple C++ app that connects to a database. I am using Microsoft visual studio 2019, and the guy uses mvs2022, so it is not working for me, there are 6 errors, all of them are LNK2028: unresolved external symbol. Is there anything that i should do differently for my version of visual studio than it says in video?

Edit: i downloaded x86 lib, now it says "cant open mysqlcppconn-static.lib"

Answer (score 0):

Usually VS2019 doesn't cause this problem, and I didn't get any errors after following the steps in the video, I suggest you watch this tutorial carefully.

```
cant open mysqlcppconn-static.lib
```

This error is caused by not loading the library directory correctly, I suggest you refer to the following steps.

1.C/C++->general->additional inlcude directories->mysql8.0.31-64\include\jdbc

2.C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor definitions->STATIC_CONCPP;

3.Linker->general->additional library directories->mysql8.0.31-64\lib64\vs14

4.Linker->Input->mysqlcppconn-static.lib

**PS: The last arrow in each step is the content you need to enter.**

Comment: I did exactly that. It just didnt work. Now i downloaded VS2022 and it works perfectly there. I guess this issue has something to do with my PC configurations or something, not with VS itself. I encounter some errors that are there only on machines with processor like mine from time to time